# Wav file becomes too large by converting from m4a file

Tags: audio, wav, m4a

I have a 1.6MB m4a file which is only 1 min 43. And when I converted it to wav file, it became to a 19.8MB file.

Why did the file become so large?

m4a: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mc3SmBWZEFW9ZZoCFEz8Xxwy2P-oQs2t/view

wav: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XFRD5f51BxBtQIBaiYNpTZZifCQLw3Km/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAV is a raw uncompressed file format. M4A is a compressed format. So if you want to keep quality, the WAV file will have to be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer : you are comparing between a zip and non zip file of media.

wav : PCM data - which is uncompressed data. ( un zip file )

m4s: AAC data - AAC is compressed data. ( zip file)

Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) is an audio coding standard for lossy digital audio compression.